# SDRAM and DDRAM

Tags: memory

Hi while browsing to buy a new computer today I finally found one that I like and fits my budget on Dell's website ( http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-8300/fs ). The only thing I don't like about it is that it has SDRAM instead of DDRAM.

What is the deference beetween SDRAM and DDRAM?

From what I read on a variety of forums I learnt that DDRAM transfers data twice as fast then SDRAM.

Those that mean for example that 16GB of SDRAM is the equivalent of 8GB of DDRAM? And if that is true for the listed computer will I be able to replace the SDRAM with DDRAM , I mean will the motherboard be compatible?

The computer will be used for a variety of things (gaming , movies , programming ) so I require it to be powerful.

Comment: This computer contains `DDR3 SDRAM` which is the current incarnation of SDRAM. Have a look at the summary box on the right which tells "8GB DDR3 SDRAM at 1333MHz - 4 DIMMs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only thing I don't like about it is that it has SDRAM instead of DDRAM.

Not sure where you inferred that - the [specs](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-8300/pd?oc=fxdwmt1&model_id=xps-8300) say it's DDR3-SDRAM.

> Those that mean for example that 16GB of SDRAM is the equivalent of 8GB of DDRAM?

No, it means that DDR SDRAM transfers data at the rising *and* falling edge of the clock cycle, thereby theoretically doubling the data transfer rate (hence DDR: Dual Data Rate). Data transfer speed has got nothing to do with RAM capacity.

> And if that is true for the listed computer will I be able to replace the SDRAM with DDRAM , I mean will the motherboard be compatible?

It's DDR3 RAM, you don't have to swap anything